# Avoid testsuite embedding code-under-test with browserify

Tags: javascript, babeljs, browserify

I have inherited [a project](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs) whose [tests](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/tree/master/auto_tests/tests) are compiled (with babeljs-7) from ES6 to ES5 first, then bundled (with browserify) into a huge `.js` file, which is then [run](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/auto_tests/runner.html) under PhantomJS. Unfortunately, I barely know ES3? ES5?

This complex process however embeds the code-under-test into that huge `.js` file as well because of [lines](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/a1c3cd640aabb70e909535aca81a6de27a364241/auto_tests/tests/xhr.js#L14) like `import Dygraph from '../../src/dygraph';` which is unfortunate and *additionally* prevents testing e.g. the minified js bundle. (This is just one example; basically **all** imports from `../../src/` *must* go away… and I *think* I’d also prefer to load those from `../../src/extras/` separately, as that’s what browsers in prod do.)

How do I split things up so that I can add the code-under-test into the [runner](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/auto_tests/runner.html) as a separate `<script …></script>` tag, like things do in production, and the tests will require the runner to do that and stop embedding the code-under-test, without breaking the babeljs and browserify chains? I can then do the remaining splitting like optionally test the minified code and accounting for the stripping of some debug functionality in it.